# Unable To Navigate To View Folder In Root Directory To Save Layout In Sitecore 9

Tags: visual-studio, layout, directory, sitecore

I am a beginner in Sitecore and following this blog [Sitecore: Working with Layout](https://srikaracharya.wordpress.com/2017/03/09/sitecore-layout/comment-page-1/?unapproved=643&moderation-hash=8dee71a3039db1b2e685b14ff03ec8e7#comment-643) the only difference is while his Sitecore app is hosted on his system server mine is on an Azure server. I was able to follow the steps to step 18 but on attempting to save the created layout in the Views/Shared folder I can't find the directory. I can only see the /sitecore directory which is a step down. I also tried to simply enter the directory in the space provided but I get an error message of "Item Cannot Be Found".
Attached is a picture with the different folder structures
Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks
[image: Different folder structure issue]

Comment: The screen on the left, which I believe is from the blog post, is the screen after you click "create" button on the screen on the left. See it here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7n34vsgm4ii29c/2020-01-12_13-00-00.mp4?dl=0

Comment: If you need to create a folder in Sitecore (right image) the layout items are here. /sitecore/layout/Layouts

Comment: Thanks for the video, I tried this same process but when the next button is clicked I doesn't show the full web root tree structure but only the folders below the sitecore directory.
@Create a folder, oh nope I am trying to navigate to the views folder. So I may make changes to the home view in visual studio.

Comment: A thought just crossed my mind, that perhaps the restriction is based on the administrator privilege given and thats why to an extent my access to the entire tree structure is restricted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use the ftp app like filezilla or total commander to connect to the server to create the folder path needed and then use the layout/layouts path field section on the sitecore environment to link the page/template file to the existing folder created.